# Drag and Drop Multiple Files and assign the files to an input tag

Tags: javascript, php, html, drag-and-drop

I am having a problem with uploading multiple files using drag and drop. I want all the files dragged to an area be assigned to the input type=file multiple.

Comment: and what is the problem you're having?

Comment: the problem is it is not really uploading unlike if i used the inpout type file...